# Unable to load en_US.json file in angularjs using angular-translate-loader-static-files

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

```js
'use strict';

/*
 * AngularJS module declaration for sm-ui.header. This is where all the dependencies
 * for this module/component are to be declared.
 */
angular.module('sm-ui.header')
//.value('language','en')
.config(function($translateProvider){
/*
    $translateProvider.translations('en',{
        CURRENT_USER_NAME : 'Current User',
        LOG_OUT : 'Logout',
        MENU : 'MENU'
    });
    $translateProvider.translations('es',{
        CURRENT_USER_NAME : 'Usuario Actual',
        LOG_OUT : 'Cerrar sesión',
        MENU : 'MENÚ'
    });
    $translateProvider.use('en');
*/
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en_US');
    $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
        prefix: '/app/languages/',
        suffix: '.json'
    });
})
.config(HeaderConfig);

function HeaderConfig($routeProvider) {

    
    $routeProvider.when('/header', {
        templateUrl: 'header/header.html',
        controller: 'HeaderCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'header'
    });
}

en_US.json file
{
        "CURRENT_USER_NAME" : "Current User",
        "LOG_OUT" : "Logout",
        "MENU" : "MENU"
}
```

---

Hi,
I am getting "http://localhost:9000/app/languages/en_US.json Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"
I am using brackets Text editor.
When i try to open http://localhost:9000/app/languages/en_US.json file on my browser , it is giving me cannot GET /app/languages/en_US.json file.

Can you please help me? Thanks.

Comment: you using express too? have some build:dist? may be .json file is ignored in dist, you may need to put it in assets folder.

Comment: No. I am not using express. I am using grunt. Can you please tell me how do I need to add json file path format.

Comment: do you have assets folder? like js / css / images files stored? you can put it there. like assets/i18n/en-US.json